# Getting an error when importing mechanize branch for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanize-python

I have installed mechanize library for python3.
https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3

But, when I import it, I get this error.

```
Python 3.3.3 (default, Dec 30 2013, 16:15:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Username/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
  File "/Users/Username/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/Users/Username/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _sgmllib_copy
```

But, I'm sure that mechanize is installed in the same virtualenv directory.

```
$ pip freeze
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
mechanize==0.2.6.dev-20140305
pyquery==1.2.8
Warning: cannot find svn location for mechanize==0.2.6.dev-20140305
```

I'm not used to operation in terminal, so I don't know how to fix this problem.

Could anyone please help me solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get mechanize to work on Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

The git repository you referred to uses `import` wrong. The `mechanize._html` module `import`s `_sgmllib_copy` expecting to get `mechanize._sgmllib_copy`, but that way of doing imports has been deprecated in [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). Rather it should be using relative imports, e.g. `from . import _sgmllib_copy`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So, what I need to do is fix "mechanize._html" file? I don't see that html file.

Comment: The file backing the `mechanize._html` module is called `mechanize/_html.py` of course.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3

This branch doesn't contain _sgmllib_copy.py at all. I took this file from master branch (it needs to change `print smth` to `print (smth)`). But I still don't get how import should be used. In _html.py module (it's located in mechanize folder) used

`from . import _sgmllib_copy as sgmllib`

Is this wrong? But `from . import _beautifulsoup` seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I added _sqmllib_copy from master branch and    reinstalled it. Now I have this error "IndentationError: unexpected indent"...

Comment: So you can fix this error in source file. Is it showing line number where it occurs?


Or you can try to use my fix https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tqHfR7_fJua2pwNUFmSDlIWnM/edit?usp=sharing


It installs but still doesn't work for me